# XAMPP Server Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, port

Not sure what exactly is causing this error and how to rectify the same. I suppose it's because of a port conflict or running multiple instance of mysqld, but not sure how to prevent (whichever) application from using up the port.

When I checked netstat(XAMPP) it shows port 3306 is used by mysqld.exe(should I free up that port? **if so how to?**)

OR

Do changing the MYSQl port work to resolve this error? if so how to?

**Note:** This is a guest PC, so not sure what all applications are already installed in this system, or how the system is configured previously.

Please find the error log from XAMPP below.

```
   2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 2e50 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1665294
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] IPv6 is available.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [ERROR] Aborting

    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Binlog end
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
    2015-05-28 20:42:58 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1665304
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
    2015-05-28 20:42:59 11488 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: use lsof -i TCP:3306 to check which program binds port 3306

99% sure this is because you are already running a MYSQL Server on that port. 
Change target port, or stop the other server

Comment: @NickRobins Thanks for the input.

It's not a familiar PC, so not sure what application is using up the port. Please also describe "How to?" for your suggestions. I'm not a pro at this.

I entered what you suggested in the Command Prompt(got an error):
************************************************************


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

H:\>lsof -i TCP:3306
'lsof' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
*****************************************************

Answer (score 0):

According to your statements, you had already checked the port and found it has been occupied.So I advice you to change port.If you would like to change the default port(not recommended). Please find my.ini in mysql's instance path, for example **D:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini**. and then edit the port below *[client]* and *[mysqld]* like this:

```
[client]
no-beep
# pipe
# socket=0.0
port=3306 #change to 3307
...
[mysqld]
...
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306 #change to 3307
```

then save it,restart the service.

By the way, If you want to run different mysqls in different ports, you should do more things.